# How to define ChekBoxes in Java?

Tags: java, android

I face a problem in defining the `CheckBox` in Java because I dont want to define it in a XML layout file.

I get the count of a `HashTable`. I want to display CheckBoxes according to the number of that HashTable count.

Here is the code

```
public class SHO extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }
}
```

In this class I want to define the chekboxes without using the XML layout file.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Show please some code you already have.

Comment: Quote some code so that we can understand you better. Also show the errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just adding them to your view and tinkering with it?

If we assume you have a LinearLayout as your root view, then you could do:

```
    CheckBox mCheckbox = new CheckBox(this);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_id);
    mLinearLayout.addView(mCheckbox);
```

That's the most simple way to add a checkbox dynamically. If you need more of 'em, just do it in a for loop that is controlled by the amount of hash tables?

**Edit**: Obviously, there's a lot of ways to add 'em and control your view through code, but these are just the very basics.

Pretty sure there's a lot of Google results if you try something like "android ui dynamically" or whatever.

Comment: I am doing this but its not working...

`public class SHO extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CheckBox mCheckbox = new CheckBox(this);
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin1);
        mLinearLayout.addView(mCheckbox);
  } 
}`

Comment: @Masooma Works for me, tried it in my own code. So need a little more info than that to help out. For example, post your full source code and your xml in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class dic_tut3 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
    ll.addView(tv);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");
    ll.addView(et);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("I don't do anything, but I was added dynamically. :)");
    ll.addView(b);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
        ll.addView(cb);
    }
    this.setContentView(sv);
}
```

}